# Can I use Jetty to deploy my project which doesn't have a web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jetty, web.xml

I have a Spring-Maven project, which i configured with Java classes, without web.xml. When i deploy it with "mvn jetty:run" i have this error "**web.xml does not exist at location ../src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**".

This is my plugin which i defined in pom.xml.

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

As i read from the Jetty Documentation we can define the web.xml location in the configuration of `jetty:run` goal. Can we also configure this so that the Jetty uses my WebConfig class as web.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a Jetty version which doesn't support the Servlet 3.0 specification and as such a web.xml is mandatory. Use a new Jetty version for Servlet 3.0 (and xml less configuration) support.

Switch to the eclipse version of the plugin

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
</plugin>
```

More information in the Jetty/Eclipse [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html).

Comment: Agreed, there have been [over 140 releases of jetty](https://gist.github.com/joakime/642ba1dbe2563fabfcd8#file-jetty-versions-txt-L1-L146) since version 6.1.10